# First buffer from UDP connection contains junk - subsequent connections are fine

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm *really* going to try to avoid posting my entire project on here - unless it's needed :)
I have a client/server program I'm writing where the client contacts the server via a UDP port, and expects to receive a packet in the format `"@7777~15~3701"` - the first time I connect, I get garbage in the buffer. However, once the client exits, and I launch it again, the next buffer `"@7777~15~3702"` comes through just fine.

```
int
RoutingManager::SendMessage(struct sockaddr_in toNode, char buffer[1024])
{
    #if logging > 1
        cout << "Sending: " << buffer << endl;
    #endif

    int n;
    unsigned int length = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    //buffer = "@7777~15~3702"
    n = sendto(mySocket, buffer, strlen(buffer),0,
                (const struct sockaddr *)&toNode,length);

    if (n < strlen(buffer))
        perror("Sendto");

    cout << "Sent: " << n << " bytes of data\n";
}
```

.. the buffer I pass in here is generated from:

```
//FIXED: This was the source of my issue it appears - a corrected
//implementation of this method has been included at the bottom.
char*
RoutingManager::GenerateConnectionString(struct Node n)
{
    char buffer[512];
    bzero(buffer,512);
    sprintf(buffer, "@7777~15~%d", n.id);
    cout << MYPORT << endl;
    return buffer;
}
```

**Server Output:**

```
Sending: @7777~15~3701
Sent: 1 bytes of data
Waiting for nodes...
```

**Client Side:**

```
RoutingNode::GetMyID()
{
    int n;
    char buffer[256];
    bzero(buffer,256);
    unsigned int length = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    struct sockaddr_in from;

    n = sendto(mySocket,"!", strlen("!"),0,(const struct sockaddr *)&server,length);

    if (n < 0) 
        perror("Sendto");

    //once we have our information from the manager, let's hog some cpu
        //remove this crap when stuff gets more reliable
        fcntl(mySocket, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

    while(buffer[0] != '@')
        n = recvfrom(mySocket,buffer,256,0,(struct sockaddr *)&from, &length);

    if (n < 0) 
        perror("recvfrom");

    parser.ParseMessage(buffer, fromNode, messages);
}
```

When I parse the message:

```
bool
RoutingMessage::ParseMessage(char* buffer, int &fromNode, map<int, string> &messages, const int MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE, 
                                const int MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE, const char* const DELIMITER)
{
    #if logging > 1
        cout << "Buffer: " << buffer << endl;
    #endif

    if (buffer[0] != '@')
    {
        perror("Buffer malformated!");
        return false;
    }

    //remove the '@'
    buffer++;

    char buf[MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE];
    strcpy(buf, buffer);
    char* temp = strtok(buf, DELIMITER);
    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        perror("Buffer malformated!");
        return false;
    }

    fromNode = atoi(temp);
    temp = strtok(NULL, DELIMITER);

    vector<string> tokens;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        string val(temp);
        tokens.push_back(val);
        temp = strtok(NULL, DELIMITER);
    }

    //store messages in the map: <message-type>, <message>
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i+=2)
        messages.insert(pair<int, string>(atoi(tokens[i].c_str()), tokens[i+1]));

    //all good
    return true;
}
```

And output the results, I get junk:

```
Buffer: <junk-symbol>
Buffer malformated!: Success
Node: 0
```

But when the client disconnects, and I relaunch the same executable, I get:

```
Buffer: @7777~15~3702
Node: 7777
Message Type: 15 Message: 3702
```

As I'd expect. Anyone know of something I could check?

### Corrected Method --

```
void
RoutingManager::GenerateConnectionString(struct Node n, char* buffer)
{
    bzero(buffer,512);
    sprintf(buffer, "@7777~15~%d", n.id);
}
```

The above seems to solve my issues.

Comment: Are you sure that you buffer is initialized properly first so it doesn't have undefined state where it might just contain some previously used data? It might be that compiler is optimizing away the `bzero()` function.

Comment: I edited my post with more details about this - I would hate to think compilers would optimize out a `bzero()` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to be in `GenerateConnectionString()` function:

```
char*
RoutingManager::GenerateConnectionString(struct Node n)
{
    char buffer[512];
    ....
    return buffer;
}
```

It returns a pointer to a local variable.
So the returned pointer points to the stack. So the data will be corrupted later when the program uses stack from that area.

Comment: This totally makes sense at first.. but then why are subsequent calls working just fine? **~Edit:** <3

Comment: @MrDuk: it might be just luck, in the sense that the memory is allocated in later calls to another unused buffer.